# Image of a polyhedral set under a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analysis, linear-transformations, convex-analysis

I say that a subset $P$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a **polyhedral set** iff there exists some positive integer $m$, a matrix $A\in Mat(m\times n,\mathbb{R})$ and a column vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $P=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid Ax\le b\}$. When $x$ and $y$ are two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I write $x\le y$ to say that $x_i\le y_i$ for all $i=1,\dots, m$.

---

Now let $T\in Mat(m\times n,\mathbb{R})$ e let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be the linear transformation defined by $f(x)=Tx$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
My problem is to prove that **if P is a polyhedral set, then also the image of $P$ under f, i.e. $f(P)=\{Tx\mid x\in\mathbb{R}^n\text{ and }Ax\le b\}$, is a polyhedral set**.

---

The idea is to show that there exists a $p\times m$ matrix $M$, for some positive integer $p$, and a column vector $\beta$ such that $f(P)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^m\mid My\le\beta\}$. But I don't how to show this latter thing. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: The condensed notation $Ax \leqslant b$ is nothing but a way of writing a number of half-spaces $\langle x, a_i \rangle \leqslant b_i$. Consider what happens to these half-spaces under $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

You can reduce it to the fact: the projection of a polyhedral set is a polyhedral set. This because the graph of a linear map defined on a polyhedral set is again a polyhedral set.  The fact about projection can be reduced to projection of a polyhedral set from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. For the last statement see [F-M elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination).

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, your hint has been very usefull. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnMax6: You are very welcome!  About the result: it gives an algorithm for the inequalities of the image, but it is not that efficient. The simplex algorithm  for the image of a functional on a polyhedral set is much better.  Also:  a cone given by a finite set of generators can also be given as a set of inequalities. Similar for bounded polyhedral sets (convex hulls of finite sets).  Cheers!